# How to get the column other value in dropdown box without refreshing the page in php ajax mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table subject_tbl and i want to print the `subjectDesc` value in the input text area after selecting in the combobox

`gradelevel_tbl`:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    subject_id       |   subjectCode    |   subjectDesc    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     Math 1       |       Algebra    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     Math 2       |       Geometry   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

HTML:

```
<select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value="" selected>Choose Subject</option>
        <?php    
        $qry="Select * from subject_tbl";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
        while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        extract($row);
        echo "<option value='".$subject_id."'>".$subjectCode."</option>";
        }; ?>
</select></p>

//Put the subjecDesc value here
<p>Subject Description: &nbsp; &nbsp;
<br><input type="text" name="subjdesc" id="subjdesc" disabled></p>
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#subject").on('change', function () {
$("#subjdesc").val($(this).val());
});});
```

Comment: to me this doesn't make sense. You are including `selectsubject.php` to provide the options for the select menu and using that same script as the ajax endpoint and trying to add the value from `selectsubject.php` to a text field.??

Comment: ow my bad i put the wrong codes i will edit it

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly the aim is to populate the text field with the description when the select menu changes?

If you assign a `dataset` attribute to each `option` in the loop - with the value from the `gradelevel_tbl` table some simple javascript should achieve your goal without needing further ajax calls.

```
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
    extract( $row );
    echo "<option value='{$subject_id}' data-description='{$subjectDesc}'>{$subjectCode}";
}



<script>
    document.getElementById('subject').onchange=function(event){
        var el=event.target;
        document.getElementById('subjdesc').value=el.dataset.description;
    }
</script>
```